# How do I get the exit angle of a body?

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, vector-analysis, angle, solid-angle

I have a 3D environment with vectors $(x, y, z)$.

For example:

- Room size $10 \times 10 \times 10$
- Bulb in the position $(3,5,10)$
- Measuring points: $(5,5,0), (1,1,0), (5, 0, 5)$,  etc.

A light bulb emits a certain amount of light $(I)$ in one direction, for example in the horizontal angle $20$, and vertical angle $40$, emits $100$ candles $(I)$.

[image]

As you can see in the picture I have a light bulb that emits light, and a point where I will measure it $(P)$.

From the bulb comes out in the direction of $P$, a line $(I)$.

That is, from the bulb, at a horizontal angle and a vertical angle comes line $(I)$.

The question is if I only have the positions of the bulb and the measuring point, how do I obtain that horizontal and vertical angle of the bulb?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: You also need a coordinate system to orient yourself. At least you need a sense of the "vertical" direction in order to define the plane where angle $y$ is defined. In addition you need a sense of which direction the line _CP_ goes to. In the picture, the direction of the sidewalk gives this sense.

Comment: I have all the information of the environment, when I create it in the software, the only thing that is not calculated are the horizontal and vertical angles

Comment: You need to edit the question and include what you have, because at it is now there isn't enough information to answer your question without answerers doing their own assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the location of the point *C* and the height $h$ above which the bulb rests then with trigonometry you know that $$\tan y = \frac{\| CP \|}{h}$$

The angular location of *P* on the *xz* plane is

$$ \tan g = \frac{P_x-C_x}{P_z-C_z} $$ where $x$ is perpendicular to the road and $z$ is along the sidewalk.